# Is every basis a subbasis?

Tags: general-topology

In topology, is every basis a subbasis?

Which means, is one basis of a topology also one subbasis of that topology?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact the definitin of subbasis is loose, take any finite intersection of elements from the subbasis to form open sets, along with the original set itself form a basis on the set. So because any basis can obviously generate itself, it must indeed be a subbasis.

However, the converse may not be true.
Take the real line equipped with standard topology, it is generated by the sets of intersections of open rays $(-\infty,a)$ and $(b,\infty)$. They form a subbasis because you can get any open set $(a,b)$ from the intersection $(a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b)$. But it is not a basis because there is no smaller ray that is a subset of $(a,b)$